# Implement Recurring Classes/Events

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have to implement upcoming classes functionality. Upcoming classes can be repeated weekly or monthly. User will only create it once and repeat logic should be handled from back end. There should be no data duplication.

Listing api should return the first 10 upcoming classes where date >= today date.

[Add live or upcoming Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJcF8.png)
[Upcoming Class listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoNIM.png)

The last tried solution is:

1. calculate the next 100 dates based on weekly or monthly interval and store it in a list named repeated_dates.
2. write a scheduler which will get the last repeated date and if it less than today date then calculate the next 100 dates and update the list.
3. filter out upcoming classes based on repeated_dates list.

The issue is:

1. If I filter out from list, I only get the class object. I don't know which date is matched.
2. If there is only two classes, then it should return 1st 10 classes from these two based on dates >= today date. But in this solution, it will only return 2.

Here is the model:

```
REPEAT_CHOICES = (
    ('no_repeat', 'Does not repeat'),
    ('repeat_weekly', 'Repeat Weekly'),
    ('repeat_monthly', 'Repeat Monthly'),
)


def image_path(instance, filename):
    if filename:
        extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    else:
        extension = "png"
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), extension)
    return os.path.join("live-class-images", filename)


class LiveClass(BaseModel):
    """
    A model which stores the information of live classes in a course and has one-to-many
    relationship with course.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])])
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    zoom_link = models.URLField()
    repeat_class = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=REPEAT_CHOICES)
    repeated_dates = models.JSONField(default=list)
    last_repeated_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name="live_class", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def formatted_date(self):
        day = self.date.day
        day_suffix = 'th' if 11 <= day <= 13 else {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}.get(day % 10, 'th')
        return self.date.strftime(f"%A {day}{day_suffix} %B %Y")

    @property
    def remaining_duration(self):
        current_datetime = timezone.now()
        target_datetime = datetime.combine(self.date, self.start_time)
        target_datetime = timezone.make_aware(target_datetime, timezone.get_default_timezone())

        time_difference = target_datetime - current_datetime
        remaining_days = max(time_difference.days, 0)
        remaining_seconds = time_difference.seconds
        remaining_hours, remaining_minutes = divmod(remaining_seconds, 3600)
        remaining_minutes //= 60

        return {
            "remaining_days": remaining_days,
            "remaining_hours": remaining_hours,
            "remaining_minutes": remaining_minutes
        }
```

Any suggestions or other solutions?

Comment: **Point # 2**
If there is only two classes, then it should return 1st 10 classes from these two based on dates >= today date. But in this solution, it will only return 2.


**Explanation:**
Physically, there are two classes which are repeated weekly. That's why logically 200 classes. So, when I filter repeated_dates >= today_date, it should return 1st 10.